# implementing other grants when only authorization code is available

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

I am creating web and mobile apps that reimplement an existing desktop app via the desktop apps publicly available API. This API only provides the Authorization Code Grant path for authentication, which would require me to either:

1. somehow securely store the client secret in the app
2. Implement PKCE & Implicit auth endpoints in my webserver as a pass-through to the API
3. Have my own auth system (via auth0 or equivalent), which the user then links to their API account

**Is 2 possible, or is 3 my only real option?**

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Wow, my question was super vague, fixed now. "Can I implement PKCE and Implicit auth on my own webserver in a reasonable way?"

Comment: instead of implementing oauth yourself I think the better way is to use some existing library :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Obviously for 3 I would want to use something like auth0 so i'm not actually managing usernames/passwords, but for 2, are there libraries that do this for me? I was unable to find any.

Comment: what technology you use?

Comment: Either Node.js or asp.net core (I have no preference)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 2 is possible, and is much more simple than I imagined. In the following examples **Client** is the web or mobile app, **Server** is your server, and **API** is the api you are trying to reach that only supports Auth Codes

for web (Implicit):

1. Client sends a standard Implicit request to Server
2. Server parses this request, then restructures it as an Auth Code request and forwards to API
3. API validates user login, and sends Auth Code to Server
4. Server sends Auth Code back to API
5. API returns access token and refresh
6. Server returns only access token to Client

for mobile (PKCE):

1. Client sends a standard PKCE request to Server
2. Server parses this request, then restructures it as an Auth Code request and forwards to API
3. API validates user login, and sends Auth Code to Server
4. Sever sends Auth Code to Client
5. Client sends Auth Code and Verifier to Client
6. Server verifies sends Auth Code back to API
7. API returns access token and refresh